# Raku: how to sort `dir` results by directory age?

Tags: raku

I am trying to get a list of directories by age in Raku, which is equivalent to Bash `ls -tl | grep ^dr` but I am unsure how to sort the results by age, if this is even possible

`for dir (test => {$_.IO.d}) -> $dir {...}`

how can I sort these results by directory age?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
dir(test => *.IO.d) .sort: *.changed
```

---

Afaik the `-t` in `ls -tl` corresponds to [the `IO::Path` method `.changed`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Path#method_changed)

Note that there's no space between `dir` and `(test...)`. That lack of space is very important. In P6, `foo(bar,baz)` means something completely different than `foo (bar,baz)`:

```
# Call `foo` with two arguments `bar` and `baz`:
foo(bar, baz);

# Juxtapose identifier `foo` with a single `List` of 2 elements (bar, baz): 
foo (bar,baz);

# Juxtapose identifier `foo` with two `List`s: 
foo (bar,baz), (qux, waldo);
```

In the latter cases, if a symbol `&foo` has been declared (which is what a `sub foo ...` does) then `foo` will be called, just as it was with the first case, but this time it'll be with either one `List` (of two elements) as its only argument or two arguments (two `List`s). If a symbol `&foo` has *not* been declared but a symbol `foo` has, then you'll get compile-time syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Use [nqp::stat](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/docs/ops.markdown#stat):

```
use nqp;
my @sorted = dir($*CWD).sort({ nqp::stat($_.Str, nqp::const::STAT_CREATETIME) });
```

Comment: I don't think this is really a good idea. nqp is not really intended for end users, it's not properly documented, and there's a straightforward answer provided by @raiph. I'm not sure that will buy you much speed, eithr, and it might be an obstacle for the optimizer.

Comment: My answer is not the same thing as what @raiph provided. Additionally I linked to the documentation on it. No clue why you think it would be an obstacle for the optimizer... please explain.